# Specify currency when formatting money as string

Tags: c#

I want to format a number with an associated currency into a locale-specific string. The standard `.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("xxx"))` produces the wrong output because it uses the locale's currency not the currency that the value actually represents.

I'm looking for a way to do what JQuery Globalize does, but in C# (See [here](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/currency/currency-formatter.md#example), relavent table below)

```
                                          Locale
                         -----------------------------------------
3-letter currency code | en (English) | de (German) | zh (Chinese)
---------------------- | ------------ | ----------- | ------------
USD                    | $1.00        | 1,00 $      | US$ 1.00
EUR                    | €1.00        | 1,00 €      | € 1.00
CNY                    | CN¥1.00      | 1,00 CN¥    | ￥ 1.00
JPY                    | ¥1           | 1 ¥         | JP¥ 1
GBP                    | £1.00        | 1,00 £      | £ 1.00
BRL                    | R$1.00       | 1,00 R$     | R$ 1.00
```

Comment: Your Code e.g. `1.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"))` is giving output as 1,00 € and for "en-US" the result is $1.00
What exactly you are trying?

Comment: I have 1 USD. I want to format it for the locale fr-FR. `1.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-F‌​R"))` gives "1,00 €" which is the wrong currency. I want to get "1,00 $"

Comment: Understood, this will help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.90).aspx has a list of expected results.  For fr-FR, 123,46 € is correct for c#.  It may be different in jquery, but it's a different language.  This doesn't necessarily have the culture you're looking for (I'm not sure in all honesty what it is) but it does show that your result is expected behavior.

Answer (score 5):

```
 string FormatCurrency(decimal value, string currencyCode, string locale)
 {
     var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(locale);
     var numberFormat = (NumberFormatInfo) culture.NumberFormat.Clone();
     var currencySymbol = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                                     .Where(ci => ci!=CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                     .Select(c =>{try{return new RegionInfo(c.LCID);}
                                                  catch{return null;}})
                                     .Where(ri=>ri!=null &&
                                                ri.ISOCurrencySymbol==currencyCode)
                                     .Select(ri => ri.CurrencySymbol)
                                     .First();
     numberFormat.CurrencySymbol = currencySymbol;
     return value.ToString("C",numberFormat);
 }
```

`FormatCurrency(1m,"USD","de")` returns `"1,00 $"` and so on but it doesn't differentiate between `CN¥` and `JP¥`, or anything like that, in any locale. The currency symbol is still the one used by its native locale. You can get the extra currency information from the [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-numbers-modern).